# Form for has_many based on records count in associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_services
end

class UserService < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :service_id, :user_id, :value

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :service
end
```

For example I have 5 services: Google, Facebook, Youtube and etc.

When I am editing a user, I should see form for each service created in services table.

Google 'Enter your account name'
Facebook 'example_account_name'
Youtube 'Enter your account name'

If user already enter name I can edit it and if name is blank I can create it. If I add another service I must see another text_field for edit it value. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All magic in `find_or_initialize`

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  ...
  <% @services.each do |service| %>
    ...
    <%= f.fields_for :user_services, service.user_services.find_or_initialize_by_user_id(@user.id) do |user_service| %>
      <%= user_service.label :value, "Set your id" %>
      <%= user_service.text_field :value %>
      <%= user_service.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Ryan Bates has the answer for you. Checkout

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

and

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Thanks, but I know about nested forms and question is different

Comment: The second link shows you how to dynamically add forms via javascript